# how to get array of object based on condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested-object

I have two array objects `arr1` and `arr2`,

`arr1` property `qty` should be less than sum of arr1 of stock and arr2 of quantity for same `name`.

How to return the array object based on comparison of property and same name in javascript

```
function getArray(arr1,arr2)
{
 return arr1.filter(i=> arr2.map(e=>i. qty < (e.quantity+i.stock)))
}
var arr1=[
  {id:1, name: "sample1", qty:2, stock: 0},
  {id:2, name: "sample2", qty:3, stock: 2},
  {id:3, name: "sample2", qty:4, stock: 1}
]

var arr2=[
  {idx:1, name:"sample1", quantity:1},
  {idx:2, name:"sample2", quantity:2},
  {idx:3, name:"sample3", quantity:1}
]
```

Expected Output,

```
[{id:1, name: "sample1", qty:2, stock: 0},
  {id:3, name: "sample2", qty:4, stock: 1}]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what research you've done and what attempts you've made to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Is `id` and `idx` the same or was this a type-o? Same for `qty` and `quantity`. What happened to `id` (or `idx`) 2?

Comment: @tigeer id and idx are different, based on same name comparing,

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
arr1.filter(item1=>item1.stock<(arr2.filter(item2=>item2.name==item1.name))[0].quantity)
```

will work as long as array2 has unique names.